# Unable to import certificate to cacerts

Tags: java, authentication, keytool

My requirement is to import a certificate for maven repositories into the global keystore.

The certificate file is named maven-cacert.cer .

I am using following command from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\` from `cmd`

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias c:\maven-cacert.cer -file c:\maven-cacert.cer.der -keystore $JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

as `maven-cacert.cer` file is in `C` directory

after pressing enter it asked to put password and after giving password it is saying like

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: $JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified
```

I also tried

```
   keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias c:\maven-cacert.cer -file c:\maven- cacert.cer.der -keystore \usr\java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

but getting same output

Please help what is going wrong with my command while `cacerts` file is inside `$JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\` directory.

Comment: and what is the value of $JAVA_HOME?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\

Comment: Not on windows it ain't, see @Quincy's answer

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try using `"%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts"`

Comment: Now its not asking for password and giving 
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\security\cacerts is not a legal command

Comment: try adding double quotes around it

Answer (score 30):

If you are using OpenJDK then the path for `cacerts` will not be available in

> `"%JAVA_HOME%"/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

it will be available in path

> `"%JAVA_HOME%"/lib/security/cacerts`

Answer (score 8):

keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias mycert -file c:\maven-cacert.cer.der -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%"\jre\lib\security\cacerts

You also had a problem with alias. It's a name, not a file. **You need to quote the "%JAVA_HOME%"**, because it has a space inside.

Answer (score 5):

Use Bellow command to import the certificate in cacerts

1. Run command prompt as Administrator
2. cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin
3. keytool -import -trustcacerts -file "certpath\certname.cer" -alias "cert_alias" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%"/jre/lib/security/cacerts
4. To view certificate keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%"/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias cert_alias

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I think JAVA_HOME was not defined for me. I just used the full path. Running from the Desktop folder, my full command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin\keytool" -import -alias fiddlercert -file fiddlerRoot.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your OS? If you are on Windows, can you try replacing $JAVA_HOME with %JAVA_HOME% and see how it goes?

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: From the question it's pretty obvious the OP is using a windows machine

Comment: Thank you guys. Being a new bee to this site, it helps to get directions from seniors like you. Will take care.

Comment: Double quotes around %JAVA_HOME worked for me. ```"%JAVA_HOME%"/lib/security/cacerts```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with following command in cmd of windows, it has worked finally:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\keytool.exe -import -trustcacerts -alias *Certificate filename* -file *full path of certificate location ending with certificatename* -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%"\lib\security\cacerts
```

Comment: thanks this one was the only one that fixed the issue for me !